# The phone is not running Samsung’s official software

Tags: samsung, rooting, twrp

Does anybody why my Samsung a40 phone briefly in red text say "The phone is not running Samsung’s official software." and then booting to Download mode. I got this error after trying to flash Twrp.

Comment: TWRP is not an Samsung official software. Even if you failed to flash TWARP completely at least some change seem to be written -> the software no longer in a genuine state.

Comment: already linked on your other question one can't install TWRP on RMM state prenormal, your only chance is flash full stock ROM from Odin and wait 7 days with registered SIM card until device gets unlocked, then read carefully instructions how to unlock bootloader correctly without activating vaultkeeper

Comment: This answered my question: https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/45894-Restoring-Stock-Firmware-with-Heimdall